# How can a input type radio return false on a check of being empty

Tags: html, forms, html-input

I've a quick question

I coded this HTML form:

```
<form action="/?controller=Settings&action=list" method=post>

<b>Default:
</b><br>
<input type="radio" class="settingsinput" 
           value="0" name="showmore" checked= "true"> Show less <br>

<input type="radio" class="settingsinput" 
           value="1" name="showmore"                > Show more <br>

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="save">

</form>
```

When I check if it's empty in PHP like that:

```
if (!empty(@$_POST["showmore"])
```

Shouldn't this always return false, because one of them is always empty?

But from what I tested, this returns true for me and I dont understand why. I checked one of it 100%.

Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found it out myself:

Answer: I took 0 as the value for the first input, and when I checked for it for being empty, it returned true, because it's content was 0.

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't be false because the first one is always selected through your `checked` attribute. Radio buttons are designed to only have 1 button selected, not all.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but then it should always say that it's not empty, right? But my code returned, that the value is empty. The explanation for it is in the answer I posted.